# Converting MapInfo to interactive layered PDF to access the full map?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I want to convert the full map I have in Pathloss 5.0/MapInfo 9.5.1 format into PDF so that I can access the whole map in a PDF file.

If I zoom in, the PDF file will be zoomed into the smallest section of the map (similar to the Pathloss/MapInfo). I can't upgrade my MapInfo version.

Comment: `ogr2ogr` can write PDF. But what do you mean with "interactive"?

Comment: So, that if I zoom in it will show me the individual links as if I am zooming in MapInfo. (In a congested area, there could be many links overlapping in Mapinfo, but if I zoom in, I can focus in one of the links, that's what I want to do with PDF).

Comment: PDF was never designed for that. You might be able to program a PDF like this with lots of JavaScript, but most PDF viewers will not support this.

Comment: I remember that feature from when my workplace was a MapInfo shop - pretty cool, you just print to the MapInfo PDF Printer and voila! - layered pdf.  Sadly, I think you're out of luck if you can't upgrade from MapInfo 9.5, pretty sure that it wasn't introduced until version 10 or 10.5.